# How does one ensure that certificate authority fallback HPKP pins are correctly set?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I'm writing an application that needs to be online and needs to be as secure as possible, including from compromised Certificate Authority (CA) attacks.

I'm ok with trusting my own certificate authority (Comodo) but what I want to be able to do is set HPKP headers and be confident that if my certificate gets compromised that I can at least fallback to creating a new one with Comodo.

How do I verify that I've set the fallback correctly short of buying a new certificate from Comodo and testing that? Also, how frequently do root certificates get rotated? It seems like the entire certificate process is pretty ill-documented.

My nginx directive is (after anonimization / reformating):

```
add_header Public-Key-Pins 
  'pin-sha256="my+domains+current+certificate+sha256+hash+=";
   pin-sha256="grX4Ta9HpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=";
   pin-sha256="lCppFqbkrlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=";
   max-age=60;
   includeSubDomains;
   report-uri="https://example.report-uri.io/r/default/hpkp/enforce"'
   always;
```

Am I okay to increase the max-age to something safer?

Edit:

It [looks like](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/357.html) the root cert is valid until sometime in 2020. Looks like [the intermediate cert](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/966/108/intermediate-1-sha-2-comodo-rsa-certification-authority) is as well. How would I transition around that time?